# How to check which action is called in yii?

Tags: php, forms, yii

I am a newbie in yii and i am trying to edit the **_form.php** that yii automatically creates for us. The **_form.php**  has been rendered partially by the **create.php** view file using
 `<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>` 

now in the **_form.php** with the following code

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'comment'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'comment',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'comment'); ?>
    </div>
```

I want this row to be displayed only when this file is rendered by **create.php** and not by **update.php** file. I can do this using an **IF** condition but I do not know how to check which file has rendered this form.
**So my question is**

```
how can i check which action has been called or which file is rendering the _form.php???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple:

```
<?php if ($this->action->id == "update") ?>
```

Comment: hahahahahha.... I was doing the same from a long time and it was not working but as i copied this from your answer it started working :-p .... BTW thanks a lot friend :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't really want to couple the partial view with the name of its owner. What you probably want is to only display the comment area *if the model is a new record*. You can do that like this:

```
<?php if($model->isNewRecord) : ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'comment'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'comment',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'comment'); ?>
</div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note that this will not *prevent* someone from crafting a HTTP request that includes a `comment` value for a model that is being updated; it will only hide the control. If you want to enforce this on the server you will need to place appropriate validation rules on `comment` based on the model's [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/).

Answer (score 1):

Your partial view shouldn't really care about where it's being rendered from. If your partial view needs additional information (to base a decision on), pass it as a parameter.

```
$this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model, 'myparam'=>'blah'));
```

And in your partial view use

```
$myparam...
```